Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _get_custom_object_labels() in taxonomy.php
I am encountering a fatal error on my WordPress website, which is hosted on Microsoft Windows Azure. The error occurs when I try to access the backend of my WordPress site. Here are the details:
**Error Message:
**
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _get_custom_object_labels() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\taxonomy.php:722 Stack trace: 
#0 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\class-wp-taxonomy.php(486): get_taxonomy_labels() 
#1 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\class-wp-taxonomy.php(290): WP_Taxonomy->set_props() 
#2 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\taxonomy.php(532): WP_Taxonomy->__construct() 
#3 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\taxonomy.php(82): register_taxonomy() 
#4 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-settings.php(402): create_initial_taxonomies() 
#5 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-config.php(98): require_once('D:\\home\\site\\ww...') 
#6 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-load.php(50): require_once('D:\\home\\site\\ww...') 
#7 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('D:\\home\\site\\ww...') 
#8 D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('D:\\home\\site\\ww...') 
#9 {main} 
  thrown in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 722


Steps Taken:
Checked PHP Version:
PHP version is 7.4.30.
Ensured All Core Files Are Present:
Re-uploaded the wp-includes and wp-admin directory from a fresh WordPress installation to ensure no core files are missing.
I have tried disabling all plugins and switching to a default theme, but the issue persists.
Request:
Could anyone provide guidance on resolving this fatal error or point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Thats a WordPress function. This function’s access is marked private. This means it is not intended for use by plugin or theme developers, only in other core functions. It is listed here for completeness.

This suggests either a poor WP install OR that something you are using is using this function incorrectly
